# Mass instantiate or build objects in ActiveRecord quickly in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a financial app that generates dynamic data from the database.  Projected daily revenue numbers, for example, are generated and outputted as SQL records (`PG:Result` in PostgreSQL 9.4). How do I instantiate or build thousands of ActiveRecord objects quickly?  To loop through each SQL record is taking too long.

Note that this is not a database issue, because I do NOT need to save to the database (in which case a mass insertion SQL statement would work). These numbers are dynamic so I don't have to create and save objects.  The reason I want to build ActiveRecord objects is so that I can easily sort and filter through the numbers using AR methods such as `WHERE` and `FIND` (for example, sorting the objects by sheet ID and/or date).  I noticed that keeping it as `PG:Result` saves time, but sorting through the results (which is just an array of hashes) requires messy code. A sample object, `Flow`, is below:

```
Flow.new
  value_subunit: 10,
  sheet_id: 1,
  is_actual: true,
  period_start: '2015-01-01'
end
```

The SQL query output looks like the following:

```
sheet_id  value_subunit is_actual period_start
----------------------------------------------
1         10            1         '2015-01-01'
2         20            0         '2015-02-01'
```

Comment: Why can't you do all the logic inside the database? Relational databases are a lot better at managing thousands of rows than Ruby. You'd even have the option of slopping your data into a temp table and indexing that temp table if you need to. Database views might be another option if you need things to look like tables.

Comment: @muistooshort i agree. I originally did do it all in the database.  however, in most cases, there are more nil values than actual values.  for example, if you have 10 yr cash flow projection on a daily basis (3,650 numbers for one line), you may only have actual values for 100 of those days.  the rest are presumed zero.  i did put in a bunch of filler records in the query itself, but it seemed wasteful to transport x times the number of records.

Answer (score 0):

Try [activerecord-import](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import). This blog talks about it: https://blog.codeship.com/speed-up-activerecord/

Comment: thanks for your answer; however since I do not need to persist the data in the database, this gem doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

Haven't used this before, but stumbled upon this a week or two ago...

https://github.com/jamis/bulk_insert